# Pure CSS lightbox with blurred dark background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to blur the darkened background without effecting my lightbox image. Any help would be appreciated as I am still trying to learn how to use the :target feature. I plan on having a few diffent images so that when I click each one this lightbox effect will work with pure css3. Also, any additional help to make this more browser friendly without javascript would be great!! As of now the code works to just create the lightbox with the see through dark background.

HTML

```
<div class="page">
<a href="#image1"><img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/20-Amazing-and-Cool-Background-For-Desktop-13.jpg" alt="" style="width: 300px; height: auto; " /></a>
</div>
<a href="#" id="image1" class="pressbox"><img   src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/20-Amazing-and-Cool-Background-For-Desktop-13.jpg" style="width: 70%; max-height:90%; " alt=""></a>
```

CSS

```
.page{
width: auto;
height: auto;
padding: 20px;
}
.pressbox {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.pressbox img   {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #444; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #444;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;   
} 
.pressbox:target {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.pressbox:target img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.page:target {
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve currently isn't possible with just CSS, but it is coming.

https://webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/

Comment: I have found a tutorial that does an overlay with blurred background, I just cannot tie it to this animation effect. The blurred css background/overlay code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/m2vEN/3/   . Would you be able to see if this contains the missing key? I have tried to get creative and wrap the initial image in a div but I do not know how to target it directly like I thoguht it should

Comment: The tutorial has the blur hard-coded on the background div - that's why it works. If you're trying to apply this style dynamically after an interaction, what you have won't work. You need a script in there to apply the styles.

Comment: I cannot hide a full screen block which has a web filter and ease in from a target? I thought I could change multiple things with one target? Sorry if I sound like an idiot haha. Just seems like the same concept as what I am doing with my lightbox. hiding it and then making opaque.

Answer (score 1):

to do this va CSS only is not such a good idea, but let's imagine it is.

To click open/close image and trigger different style on dfferent parts of the page can be helped using form elements such as radio (or checkbox).

`inputs` right ahead in the `HTML`.

anywhere in the page thumbs wrapped into `label`s related to `input`s via the attribute `for`.

Somehwere next(after) your `input`s in the code your `#overlay` holding the big images, themselves wrapped into a `label` . `#overlay` not standing in the wrapper to blur of course.

Now, once such a structure is there, you can use the `:checked ~` selector to apply styles where you wish down the DOM / document.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WrgPKG?editors=1100) but, i wouldn't recommend to use such a structure wich is meaning less and confusing once style are not loaded, even if it is fun to play around with CSS ;)

```css
:checked~.wrapper {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#overlay label {
  display: none;
}

:checked ~ #overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#a1:checked ~ #overlay label.a1
/* add each other  selector here a2, a3, .... */{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

label img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.img {
  font-size:2em;
  color:red;
  }
.img img {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[id^=a] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120%;
}
```

```html
<input id="a1" type="radio" name="test" />
<!-- as any needed -->


<div id="overlay">
  <label for="a" class="a1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nature/1" />
  </label>
  <!-- as any needed -->
  <input id="a" type="radio" name="test" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1> test</h1>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <div class="img">
    My CSS lightbox image =>
    <label for="a1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/1" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So if you were to do it one way and the right way how would you? I am doing this in wordpress on a custom page so it gets a little tricky for me since I know little javascript. Using my style that I already have is there any chance you could write in the best way to do it but add the blur with the darkened background? I really wanted to do in css but you guys are saying its a no no or not possible lol. So some jquery help would be great.

Comment: @IrishRedneck I would use a ready made plugin if i would not know how to manage this. Wordpress is full of them and lightbox alike are dozens. you may then have only to look at the style sheet of the plugin in order to customize it. Javascript will be solid, CSS on older browser will break ;) , it actually can break easily

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I just wanted full control over styling and future animations with it so using a premade plugin takes that away from me kind of. I really just thought there would be a way to hide a full screen block with blurred filter and unhide it when target goes off . This target also unhiding the lightbox image.

Comment: @IrishRedneck Well, at least you have one picture with input and checked. to use :target, you will need to put your anchor in fixed position to avoid a jumpy page, but it can work too and things could be kept together ... but should not be childs of what is going to be blured

Comment: @IrishRedneck as i said earlier, the container of image should not be a child of the blured container ;) , then javascript or HTML/CSS will do. Via javascript, basicly the thumbs stand in a link, big image uri is in href. Javascript catch the click and then creates append/prepend container to body and insert the img tag and set source from the href attribute. if  no javascript, then you are linked to the big image. HTML/CSS option takes you nowhere if broken ;) this was my meaning. the choice of the risk/way building this is yours.

Comment: Well I changed it around and used some jquery like you said. Here it is !!!!   https://jsfiddle.net/w3yLx8vt/31/

Comment: @IrishRedneck great , and you can style as you wish.  for info, a :target css version  (very similar to your jquery result) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bEmWQE ;)

Comment: Oh wow, thats exactly it haha. There is one thing about the :target method I didnt like which I am curious if there was a solution. How do you get it so that if you press back it doesnt take you through each target click you did. Like if you press the images and stuff then press back it just keeps bringing them backup as if you are rewinding. Where as the jquery method you can hit back and it actually takes you back to the previous page and not the last click/stage you were at.

Comment: @IrishRedneck with the CSS :target method, when you use a link and it goes in history, javascript is again to be used to erase it/skip it from being stored in history ;)